# Textarea rotation in IE 9

Tags: rotation, internet-explorer-9, transform

An example:

```
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"  style="-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);zoom:1;">sdfjksdfhj</textarea>
```

Text is there, but is invisible while unselected. In IE8 and IE7 it rotates fine using filter. If I try filter on IE9 (transform rotate is removed) text area is all black. Am I missing something

Comment: it sounds like a bug in the browser. Can't test it now, but I do recall reading about a few glitches with rotation of dynamic content in IE9. Not sure how you'd resolve it. But I guess the real question is *why* would you want to rotate a user input field? Presenting user input sideways surely doesn't sound like a good user experience.

Comment: It's not aesthetics that I need. Text is moslty for reading, but I want to keep the editing functionality for special cases. For using simple divs I need to rewrite large chunks of my code, because everything is generated in real time. And IE9 is the only misbehaving kid (IE7 and 8 work fine)